# CountDownTimer java equivalent

Tags: java, swing, timer, countdown

I am making an application where I use the Twitter API. I can reach the API limit after 180 API calls and what I want to do when I reach that limit is start a timer which is going to update a countdown (jLabel) every 1 seconds and the most important part is that the timer will finish after a certain X amount of seconds (taken from the API call).

Is there a desktop Java alternative for the Android CountDownTimer class?

I know I can do this but it doesn't seem proper:

```
time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > X_SECONDS_HERE * 1000) {
            cancel();
        } else {
            // Update GUI countdown here
        }
}
```

Another alternative is to use a SwingWorker with a Thread.sleep(). Are these the only alternatives?

Comment: If updating a `JLabel`, use a Swing `Timer` as opposed to the `TimerTask` or `java.util.Timer`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As @AndrewThompson pointed out:) For Swing, you generally want to use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of a java.util.Timer or TimerTask. The reason is that Swing is a single threaded framework, in which all update to the UI (in your case the label) should be made on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). With the Swing timer, the repetitive calls are made through an `ActionListener`, which acts on the EDT.

The basic construct of the `Timer` is:

```
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
```

where, `delay` is milliseconds for the initial and between-event delay, and the listener holds the callback functionality in the `actionPerformed` method. So you have something like

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    private int count = 100;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (count == 0) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource).stop();
        } else {
            // decrement the count and set the text for the label
        }
    }
});
// start the timer with a call to timer.start()
```

With the code above, the call to `actionPerformed` will occur every 100o milliseconds. So whatever repetitive action you want to occur, put the code there.

Resources:

- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: I guess this is the only way in the end..Unless of course I try to make a Timer subclass which I may try doing later.

Answer (score 2):

Java docs have a similar [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/Countdown.java) using Timer so your code looks almost right:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(i--);
        if (i< 0)
            timer.cancel();
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct already , but you will need extra parameters, example :

```
time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > X_SECONDS_HERE * 1000) {
            cancel();
        } else {
            // Update GUI countdown here
        }
}}, 1000,2000);
```

1000 means delay for `1000 millisecond`s before executing, and 2000 the task will be repeated every `2000 milliseconds`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a return method I made not too long ago for myself. It requires java 5 
and up I believe. Badically, you put a long of the time in millis and it returns a perfectly formatted string that is easier to read, try it:

```
public static String getTime(long time) {
    long timeToEdit = time;
    String textToDraw = "";
    if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time) >= 10) {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time);
    } else {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + "0" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(time);
    }
    timeToEdit -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeToEdit));
    if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit) >= 10) {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit);
    } else {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":0" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit);
    }
    timeToEdit -= TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeToEdit));
    if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit) >= 100) {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit);
    } else if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit) >= 10) {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":0" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit);
    } else {
        textToDraw = textToDraw + ":00" + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(timeToEdit);
    }
    return textToDraw;
}
```

Sorry for the ugly code formatting, im on mobile, its kinda hard to make t look nice, hopefully someone will edit it.

Comment: Oh for some reason I thought you wanted to draw the time, sorry